# Quick shortcut to dismiss notifications in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, notification, ubuntu-gnome

I have been using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to access the notifications area then <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> to cancel/dismiss notifications.

Is there a "quicker" shortcut (i.e. more direct/immediate action)?

Comment: I don't have access to a GNOME environment but does pressing `escape` do anything?

Comment: Did you check `dconf` ?

Comment: I haven't found a real solution yet, but worth noting that you can tab all the way through to "clear all" and `enter` or `space` to clear them all at once. Beats clearing them one at a time, at least.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to focus the currently displayed notification followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> works for me.

Answer (score 3):

A small hack..
Run the below command in terminal or create a shortcut with the below command.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.panel.statusArea.dateMenu._messageList._notificationSection._list.remove_all_children()'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable notifications:

1. Open the **Activities** overview and start typing *Notifications* and click on **Notifications** to open the panel.
2. Switch the toggle to *OFF*.

You can press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open the notifications tray/calendar.

Notifications will still be available in the message tray when you display it, by clicking on the clock, or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, and they will start popping up again when you switch the toggle to *ON* again.